# #1005 - Can't create table `quiz`.`choice` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") why giving this error for following query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table category(
                      cat_id INT(10),
                      category varchar(100),
                      PRIMARY KEY(cat_id)
                      );


create table question(
                      cat_id INT(10),
                      q_id INT(10),
                      question varchar(300),
                      FOREIGN KEY(cat_id) references category(cat_id),
                      PRIMARY KEY(cat_id,q_id)
                     );


create table choice(
                    choice_id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    cat_id INT(10),
                    q_id INT(10),
                    choice varchar(100),
                    iscorrect INT(1),
                    FOREIGN KEY(cat_id) REFERENCES category(cat_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY(q_id) REFERENCES question(q_id),
                    PRIMARY KEY(choice_id,cat_id,q_id)
                  );
```

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY(cat_id, q_id)`.  You have a composite primary key.

Comment: Given the current design of the `question` table, with *two* columns in the primary key... a foreign key referencing that table should consist of *two* columns.